# Unix command to list files as per string pattern preference in file name

Tags: bash, unix, grep, ls

Need to list and copy files as per pattern preference in file name-

There are 5 log files patterns are getting generated on every run and I want to copy the longest pattern match file first and give hierarchy accordingly -

Run #1 -

> runsummary_Date_TimeStamp.log

Run #2 -

> runsummary_runsummary_Date_TimeStamp.log

Run #3 -

> runsummary_runsummary_runsummary_Date_TimeStamp.log

Run #4 -

> runsummary_runsummary_runsummary_runsummary_Date_TimeStamp.log

Run #5 -

> runsummary_runsummary_runsummary_runsummary_runsummary_Date_TimeStamp.log

These all files comes in single directory now I want to copy file according the maximum number of "runsummary" string in log file name from a directory. In this case file#5 which is having maximum count of runsummary in file pattern should be picked then 4th,3rd and so on.

I have tried `grep -P`, `find` and `ls grep` but none is giving required result.

```
ls -lrt replay* |grep -P "replay"
ls -lrt replay* |grep replay

ls | grep "runsummary" | awk '{print $0 " " gsub("runsummary", "&")}'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about your use case and what you want to achieve. Where do the files come from? Why do they have these strange names? Why not something like `runsummary_1_Date_TimeStamp.log`, `runsummary_2_Date_TimeStamp.log` etc or ` `runsummary_Date_TimeStamp_1.log` etc? What do you want to do with the files? Copy/move them to different locations based on their name? Read them in a specific order? Is it OK to rename the files? Is *`Date_TimeStamp`* a placeholder for different values? Show an example of the real files and the expected result matching the example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you can do is start with the files, containing five times the prefix `runsummary` (which I will now abbreviate to `rs`).

```
do_something_with (rs_rs_rs_rs_rs_restofFileName)
move_to_dir5 (rs_rs_rs_rs_rs_restofFileName)
do_something_with (rs_rs_rs_rs_restofFileName)
move_to_dir4 (rs_rs_rs_rs_restofFileName)
do_something_with (rs_rs_rs_restofFileName)
move_to_dir3 (rs_rs_rs_restofFileName)
do_something_with (rs_rs_restofFileName)
move_to_dir2 (rs_rs_restofFileName)
do_something_with (rs_restofFileName)
move_to_dir1 (rs_restofFileName)
```

As you move the proceeded files away, they won't be used in the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

touch a_date_time.log
touch a_a_date_time.log
touch a_a_a_date_time.log
touch a_a_a_a_date_time.log
touch a_a_a_a_a_date_time.log

mkdir 1 2 3 4 5

mv *_*_*_*_*_*_*.log 5

mv *_*_*_*_*_*.log 4

mv *_*_*_*_*.log 3

mv *_*_*_*.log 2

mv *_*_*.log 1
```

Not super elegant, but it works.  It is based on the number of `_` characters.  I put one more than what is required for the runsummary since you have one between date and time as well.